# Why does Mathematica fail to numerically integrate a smooth function?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, numerical-methods

I have a function of two real variables defined in a domain which is a compact and a bounded region. The function itself is defined as a numerical integral over and interval. I need to numerically integrate my function  over the  region in question and I know that the integral exists. Indeed, if the function is being plotted in that region it is smooth and does not display any singularities nor is it wildly oscillating. However,  using NIntegrate leads to a bunch of errors of the kind "The integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries". It is obviously wrong because I know that for all those points Mathematica evaluates the function correctly when I plot it. See code snippet along with the output below:

```
`s = {5/2, 1/2, 1/3};
lowLim[A1_, A2_, s_] := 
  ArcCos[Sqrt[Min[(-A1 + 1/s[[3]])/(-1/s[[2]] + 1/s[[3]]), 1]]];
upLim[A1_, A2_, s_] := 
  ArcCos[Sqrt[
    Max[0, (-A1 + 1/s[[3]])/(-1/s[[1]] + 1/
      s[[3]]), (s[[1]] s[[2]] - A1 s[[1]] s[[2]] s[[3]] + s[[3]]^2 + 
        A2 (A1 + A2) s[[1]] s[[2]] s[[3]]^2 - 
        A2 s[[3]] (s[[1]] s[[2]] + s[[1]] s[[3]] + 
           s[[2]] s[[3]]))/((s[[1]] - s[[3]]) (s[[2]] - s[[3]]))]]];
mDensity[A1_, A2_, s_] := 
  NIntegrate[(4 Sqrt[s[[1]] s[[2]]]
       s[[3]])/(\[Sqrt]((A1 + Cos[a[2]]^2 (-(1/s[[2]]) + 1/s[[3]]) - 
           1/s[[3]]) (-A1 + Cos[a[2]]^2 (1/s[[1]] - 1/s[[3]]) + 1/
           s[[3]])) \[Sqrt](-s[[1]] s[[2]] + 
         Cos[a[2]]^2 (s[[1]] - s[[3]]) (s[[2]] - s[[3]]) + 
         A1 s[[1]] s[[2]] s[[3]] - s[[3]]^2 - 
         A2 (A1 + A2) s[[1]] s[[2]] s[[3]]^2 + 
         A2 s[[3]] (s[[1]] s[[2]] + s[[1]] s[[3]] + 
            s[[2]] s[[3]]))), {a[2], lowLim[A1, A2, s], 
    upLim[A1, A2, s]}];
NIntegrate[mDensity[A1, A2, s], {A1, 2.1, 2.4}, {A2, 1.6, 1.9}]
Plot3D[mDensity[A1, A2, s], {A1, 2.1, 2.4}, {A2, 1.6, 1.9}]`
```

[image]

My question is how do I make Mathematica compute that integral numerically?

I tried to use the EvaluationMonitor option to NIntegrate but it has not even used the monitor but instead it has produced the same error as before.

Then I thought that the error has something to do with Mathematica returning the whole input expression in case of some numerical errors so I wrapped the integrand into a Check[..,10^8]. Now the monitor did output some results but the actual output of the integration was completely ambiguous and changed completely if I replaced the 10^8 by some other big number.

```
`NIntegrate[
 Check[mDensity[A1, A2, s], 10^8], {A1, 2.1, 2.4}, {A2, 1.6, 1.9}, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> Print[{A1, A2, mDensity[A1, A2, s]}]]
`
```

[image]

###### Update:

I replaced the arguments A1_, A2_ to the integrand by A1_?NumericQ, A2_?NumericQ and I also cleared the kernel and this did the job. As far as I understand the command _? only accepts the input argument if it is numeric.

Comment: If I comment out the `NIntegrate` line just before the `Plot3D` line then the code appears to work just fine probably because `Plot3D` is picking actual numbers for `A1` and `A2` and then calling `mDensity` with those actual numbers. If I restart MMA and do not comment out the `NIntegrate` and before doing anything else I change every `A1_,A2_` to `A1_?NumericQ,A2_?NumericQ` and THEN I run the code then it appears to work for me.